# Using generics in java ENUM

Tags: java, enums

This is how I have written my enum.

```
public enum JobClass {

    START_STOP(SchedularEvent<ExceptionNotificationsJob>.class),
    EMAIL_NOTIFICATION(SchedularEvent<GenericNotificationsJob>.class);

    private Class clazz; 

    JobClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class getClazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }

}
```

However this does not compile! It throws following errors.

Multiple markers at this line

- The constructor JobClass() is undefined
- Syntax error on token ">", byte expected after this token
- The constructor JobClass() is undefined

I am not sure how I should write this.

My aim is to get `SchedularEvent<ExceptionNotificationsJob>.class` when I call   `JobClass.START_STOP.getClazz()`. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Currently](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301) you can't do this with enums. There also is no runtime `Class` representation of a parametrized type, the best you can do is use a class literal of the raw type: `SchedularEvent.class`. The solution really depends on the use, do you just need the class to create instances?

Comment: Thanks @JornVernee that helped! 
To elaborate further on my use case, I am using quartz to schedule some jobs. I want to publish some custom events from execute method for those jobs. I am using spring event listeners to listen to these events. In listener class, I wanted to identify what was exact type of Scheduler that fired the event. Was it ExceptionNotificationsJob or GenericNotificationsJob? Depending on that my rest of logic will flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that like this. `SchedularEvent<GenericNotificationsJob>.class` is not valid, because generics are erased at runtime, it only provides compile-time safety.

How you would have to rewrite the code depends on what exactly it is you want to achieve. One thing you can do is just `SchedularEvent.class`. You could also use Reflection to get the class of the containing type of your `SchedularEvent`, but that is generally not a good idea.

---

Also, you shouldn't use raw types. Replace `Class clazz` by `Class<?> clazz`.